# Connect to "on-premise" postgresql database with AWS glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue, amazon-vpc

I have a PostgreSQL database which is in effect "on premise" but I have credentials and a JDBC connection string. I want to read the table on AWS glue and use it in a job as a source, and write to S3.

But it is asking for VPC? I don't understand. I can hard code the connection in the Job? This seems like such a basic task for an ETL environment. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share the details of what exactly you are doing? What is asking for VPC?

Comment: I am going to AWS glue in the console. Selecting Connections on the left hand pane. I have my JDBC connection in hand on notepad++. I am asking to connect via JDBC. I am being asked for a "VPC" and  "subnet".

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-to-access-and-analyze-on-premises-data-stores-using-aws-glue/

Comment: Glue can not connect directly to on premise database server. VPC and subnet provided that connectivity. You might want to read about that first.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya how would I configure a VPC and subnet to be able to read from my JDBC data source? It is public, I have a working JDBC connection. I just need to get connected somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Glue can connect to any database using JDBC. This is a good toolbox to fast track pyspark coding.

Basically you need to understand where you are physically located in AWS environment. And identify or create a VPC. From there, establish your ACL and Security Group.

Good luck!